Why does defining the elements of the array b is required to get the desired output
I recently learnt about typecasting pointers. So I played around, and made this bad code:
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int* a;
    char b[]= "Hye";
    a = (int*)&b;
    *a='B';
    printf("%s\n", b);
    return 0;
}

This code gives the output 'B'.
Upon further playing around, I wrote this code:
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int* a;
    char b[]= "Hye";
    a = (int*)&b;
    *a='B';
    b[1]='y';
    b[2]='e';
    printf("%s\n", b);
    return 0;
}

The output is "Bye".
I am unable to understand what the statement *a='B'; does, and why does redefining the second and the third elements of the array changes the output?
I already used stuffs like GPT-4o, searching stuffs like typecasting pointer on google, then reading articles, and watching videos related to it to get a answer to my question. But I got none. So here I am.

"This code gives the output 'B'." so I deduce you're on a little endian computer :-) Hint: 'B' (on a little endian, ASCII-based computer) is the sequence of 4 bytes 66,  0, 0, 0.

Yeah! I am (Sorry for the late reply.I am just a noob here, so I literally had to Google what "little endian" mean)

There's a lot of undefined behavior in this code.  Some implementations could produce a segmentation violation, or certainly give different results from what you're seeing.  There is no guarantee that your char array is acceptably aligned for an int pointer, for one thing.

On almost all systems int is four bytes and char is one byte. With *a='B'; the compiler will convert the character 'B' to an int and assigns it to the four bytes pointed to by a. Depending on your systems endianness your array will become either { 'B', 0, 0, 0 }  or { 0, 0, 0, 'B' }. You beginners books should have taught you that the string null-terminator is equal to 0.

@pmg Thanks for the reply. Now that I think about it, definitely B will get implicitly converted into its ASCII value.But, still I am unable to get the connection of how the integer value will cause this strange behaviour.

@Someprogrammerdude Well, thank you! I got the answer. Now I understood this was a dumb question.

Don't play with pointers in "real code" :-)

@pmg Thanks for the advice! I will keep it in my mind. I just wanted to make sure I understand typecasting pointers

Try *a = 6650178; in the first example :-)

@pmg wow! This prints "Bye".But how does this exactly works? (I noticed 66 is the ASCII value of B. But how does "50178" output "ye".I don't think "50178" collectively or separately represent the ASCII characters 'y', 'e')

That 66 is an unfortunate coincidence, disregard that, it has no influence whatsoever on the workings at play here! Try to figure it out yourself; I'll give you a hint: think base 256.

Another hint: decimal 6650178 is hex 00657942. And your machine is little-endian.

bring it up a notch: change that 6650178 to a number that will make your program print :-)

@pmg maybe *a=2698554; will give :-)

Nice going @RajeshPaul congrats!

Also my thanks to @PaulLynch for helping me to figure it out

Thanks @pmg for helping me out! I think I will never understand how you people can know so much, yet be so humble

Just an important note that hasn't been mentioned in all our playing: it's important that the b array has 4 or more bytes ("Bye" is 4 bytes because of the zero string terminator).

@RajeshPaul Nice going figuring it out. pmg's simple "trick" is a good learning experience - nice suggestion.

@pmg Thanks! I understood here the allocated memory of the array is getting overflowed. But, in this case, from where printf is getting the null character to mark the end of printing? (Does, due to overflow the null character is written in a memory address adjacent to the array, and from there is it is reading the null character?)

The number 2698554 is 58 + 45*256 + 41*256*256 + 0*256*256*256. The 58 gives :, the 45 gives -, the 41 gives ) and the 0 gives the zero string terminator, for a total of 4 bytes. That's why it's important that the starting string is long enough!

the allocated memory of the array is NOT getting overflowed

@pmg I see the array is of 4 bytes.So it is not getting overflowed.Sorrt for my mistake
